# Can an e-mail's headers tell you if it has an attachment?

Tags: email

I'm trying to filter emails that have attachments, but in the system I'm using I only have access to the headers (for filtering). Is there a consistent way of determining if an e-mail contains attachments using only headers? (Perhaps checking if the content-type is multipart?)

Comment: Checking for mime-type='multipart/mixed' works in all emails that I've seen with Gmail. This is if you define an attachment by what Gmail shows a paperclip for.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cannot achieve your desired goal if you have access *only* to the headers. The information *may* be there as a non-standard header but that's obviously not something that you can rely on. Either get access to the body or abandon the idea.

Answer (score 3):

Mails without attachments may be content-type:multipart too, like those with text and html versions of the content. What you would have to check is c-t:multipart and then for parts that are not content-type:text/*, but for that you will need access to the body :(

Answer (score 1):

For Mime attachments, emails with a `Content-Type: multipart/mixed` would often have attachments (but don't have to). Emails with a `Content-Type:` other than `multipart/*` would not have attachments. Anything else (`multipart/alternative` being the most common) may have attachments.

And in any case, that depends what is meant by attachment. If by attachment, you mean only those mime parts that have a `attachment` `Content-Disposition`, then you won't find it out in the email header, only in the corresponding part mime headers.

Things you may not want to  consider as attachments are for instance email signatures, parts of a `multipart/related` message that are for instance images embedded in the signature of an html message...

Answer (score 0):

I got email header using belowe code:

```
 msg_header = @imap.fetch(message_id, 'RFC822.HEADER').first.attr['RFC822.HEADER']
headers = msg_header.split(/\r\n|: /)
email_header = headers[headers.index('Content-Type')+1].split(/;/)
```

Then you can decide on header this mail has attachment or not without get body.

you can check header information from [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME)
Hope this helps you.